# Where are WordPress' rewrite rules stored?

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I'm interested in understanding how WordPress' RewriteRules work and where all the rules are written to.

The function `save_mod_rewrite_rules()` seems to indicate that the rules are written to the .htaccess file where WordPress is installed, but this file only ever shows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Where are the rest of the rules output?

Comment: rewrite_rules in mysql table wp_options

Answer (score 2):

The 'option_value' of the row in the MySQL table 'wp_options' with 'option_name' = 'rewrite_rules' look like this:

```
[^wp-json/?$] => index.php?rest_route=/
[^wp-json/(.*)?] => index.php?rest_route=/$matches[1]
[^index.php/wp-json/?$] => index.php?rest_route=/
[^index.php/wp-json/(.*)?] => index.php?rest_route=/$matches[1]
[category/(.+?)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[category/(.+?)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[category/(.+?)/embed/?$] => index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&embed=true
[category/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
[category/(.+?)/?$] => index.php?category_name=$matches[1]
[tag/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?tag=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[tag/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?tag=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[tag/([^/]+)/embed/?$] => index.php?tag=$matches[1]&embed=true
[tag/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?tag=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
[tag/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?tag=$matches[1]
[type/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?post_format=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[type/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?post_format=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[type/([^/]+)/embed/?$] => index.php?post_format=$matches[1]&embed=true
[type/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?post_format=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
[type/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?post_format=$matches[1]
[robots\.txt$] => index.php?robots=1
[.*wp-(atom|rdf|rss|rss2|feed|commentsrss2)\.php$] => index.php?feed=old
[.*wp-app\.php(/.*)?$] => index.php?error=403
[.*wp-register.php$] => index.php?register=true
[feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?&feed=$matches[1]
[(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?&feed=$matches[1]
[embed/?$] => index.php?&embed=true
[page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?&paged=$matches[1]
[comments/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?&feed=$matches[1]&withcomments=1
[comments/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?&feed=$matches[1]&withcomments=1
[comments/embed/?$] => index.php?&embed=true
[search/(.+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?s=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[search/(.+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?s=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[search/(.+)/embed/?$] => index.php?s=$matches[1]&embed=true
[search/(.+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?s=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
[search/(.+)/?$] => index.php?s=$matches[1]
[author/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[author/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[author/([^/]+)/embed/?$] => index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&embed=true
[author/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
[author/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?author_name=$matches[1]
[([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&feed=$matches[4]
[([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&feed=$matches[4]
[([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/embed/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&embed=true
[([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]
[([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]
[([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&feed=$matches[3]
[([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&feed=$matches[3]
[([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/embed/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&embed=true
[([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]
[([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]
[([0-9]{4})/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[([0-9]{4})/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[([0-9]{4})/embed/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&embed=true
[([0-9]{4})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
[([0-9]{4})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]
[.?.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
[.?.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
[.?.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[.?.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[.?.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
[.?.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/embed/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&embed=true
[(.?.+?)/embed/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&embed=true
[(.?.+?)/trackback/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&tb=1
[(.?.+?)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[(.?.+?)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[(.?.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
[(.?.+?)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
[(.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]
[[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
[[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
[[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
[[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/embed/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&embed=true
[([^/]+)/embed/?$] => index.php?name=$matches[1]&embed=true
[([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?name=$matches[1]&tb=1
[([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
[([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?name=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
[([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$] => index.php?name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]
[[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
[[^/]+/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
[[^/]+/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[[^/]+/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[[^/]+/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
[[^/]+/([^/]+)/embed/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&embed=true
```

The rules are applied when the function WP::parse_request() is called.

Comment: The MySQL query for this is `SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name='rewrite_rules'`

Answer (score 1):

The function you mention writes the rules you have already seen into the `.htaccess` file and nothing more. The actual routing is done in php and is governed by a few things, e.g. the settings for permalinks in the options menu. The mod_rewrite rules only make sure that everything that does not appear to be a file is rewritten to this php router. The wordpress php router then tries to find the closest match for the page you want to see.

Comment: If the rules are written into the .htaccess file, why don't I see them there when I view it?

Comment: You have not correctly interpreted what @Sumurai8 has written. There are really two sets of rewrite rules. One contained in .htaccess which is written by save_mod_rewrite_rules() and used by the HTTP server. There is another set maintained and used by the PHP server itself. URL's are rewritten first by the HTTP server and then by the PHP server. In fact, the heavy rewriting is done by the PHP server. Everything Sumurai8 has written is absolutely correct but I think you are being mislead by your pre-conceptions.

Comment: How does the "WordPress php router" work to rewrite the URLs?